# FOREIGN KEY constraint issue even though value already exists

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, foreign-keys

I have researched into various solutions before posting on here as its my last resort. I can't seem to figure out what's going on with the code at all. The value will insert into 1 table though when i go to insert into another it gives the error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_QuizAnswer_ToQuiz".".

The value already exists in the database when i insert it, i know this because i've tested to retrieve value from database and assigned it to a label, even when i do this i get the same error. Please help.

ASPX Page

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizName" runat="server" Text="Quiz Name: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="QuizNameTextBox" Placeholder="Enter Quiz Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Label ID="nameerror" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" Text="The quiz name already exists, please create another."></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuizNameRequired" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="QuizNameTextBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The quiz name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ForCourse" runat="server" Text="For Course: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem value="1">Course51531</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem value="7">Course6</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem value="9">Course8</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem value="12">Course 11</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem value="35">Course 1sdwd</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem value="36">ewfwef</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Reattempt" runat="server" Text="Can this be re-attempted?: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="true" ID="Reattemptradio" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" ControlToValidate="Reattemptradio" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a value."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Reattemp1" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="How many times?: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="reattemptbox1" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Continue" CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="View2" ToolTip="Click here to create questions for the quiz." runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="Continue_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Question No: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Question Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Question Type:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="---Select---"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Drop Down Menu" Value="Drop Down Menu"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Radio Buttons" Value="Radio Buttons"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Check Box" Value="Check Box"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="TextBox" Value="TextBox"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Multi Line Response" Value="Multi Line Response"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Pass Mark: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="SwitchViewByID" CommandArgument="View3" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ResponseLabel11" runat="server" Text="Enter another Response: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ResponseTextBox11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="ResponseTextBox11" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="A response is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td>Note: The response in this textbox should be an answer.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="ResponseLabel12" runat="server" Text="Enter another Response: "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ResponseTextBox12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" ControlToValidate="ResponseTextBox12" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Another response is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Answer12" Text="Is Answer?" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```

c# File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
int quizid = 0;
int check = 0;
int questid = 0;
int counter = 1;
int count = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Continue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Quiz] ([QuizName], [CourseId], [AllowedAttempts]) VALUES (@QuizName, @CourseId, @AllowedAttempts)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = QuizNameTextBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            if (Reattemptradio.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Yes")
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllowedAttempts", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(reattemptbox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllowedAttempts", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT QuizId FROM Quiz WHERE (QuizName = '" + QuizNameTextBox.Text + "')";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    quizid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["QuizId"]);
                    ViewState["quiz"] = quizid;
                }
            }
        }
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [QuizQuestion] ([QuizId], [QuestionNo], [QuestionType], [QuestionName], [QuestionMark]) VALUES (@QuizId, @QuestionNo, @QuestionType, @QuestionName, @QuestionMark)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quizid;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionMark", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + counter + 1;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT QuizQuestionId FROM QuizQuestion WHERE (QuestionName = '" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    questid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["QuizQuestionId"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [QuizAnswer] ([QuizId], [QuizQuestionId], [Response], [Sequence], [CorrectResponse]) VALUES (@QuizId, @QuizQuestionId, @Response, @Sequence, @CorrectResponse)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["quiz"]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizQuestionId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(questid);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Response", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ResponseTextBox11.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sequence", SqlDbType.Int).Value = count;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorrectResponse", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToBoolean("True");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}}
```

QuizAnswer Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuizAnswer] 
(
    [QuizAnswerId]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuizQuestionId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [QuizId]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [Response]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Sequence]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [CorrectResponse] BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuizAnswerId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuizAnswer_ToQuizQuestion] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([QuizQuestionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[QuizQuestion] ([QuizQuestionId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_QuizAnswer_ToQuiz] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([QuizId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Quiz] ([QuizId])
);
```

Quiz table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quiz] 
(
    [QuizId]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [QuizName]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [CourseId]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [TotalMarks]      INT           DEFAULT ((1)) NULL,
    [PassMarks]       INT           NULL,
    [AllowedAttempts] INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]        BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QuizId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Quiz_ToCourse] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Course] ([CourseId])
);
```

Comment: How does viewstate["quiz"] get assigned too if Button1 is never clicked?  Have you tried debugging with a breakpoint or profiled to see what values are being passed sql?

Comment: I'm not having a problem with Button1, the problem is with button2. I click that and no quiz id, i've tested this using a label to see if a value is assigned and it is. Though on button 2 click when inserting i get the foreign key constraint error.

Comment: I understand that.  The foreign key constraint that's failing is "quizId" have you confirmed that your quizId being passed in under button2 click has its value assigned properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you are attempting to store the answers into the QuizAnswer table in the Button2_Click event, it looks like you are pulling the QuizId from ViewState:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["quiz"]);
```

You may want to set a breakpoint at this point and ensure that the QuizId value is in fact coming back correctly or if it is being lost during the postback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely exists in the line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuizId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["quiz"]);
```

either put a breakpoint past this line to see what your parameters value is being assigned too, or run a sql profiler to see what's actually being passed in.

You are likely not properly assigning your `quizId` to `ViewState["quiz"]`

Comment: At first the value was being lost after postback. Though i assigned the value to a label and now it seems to be working even after postback.

Comment: so problem solved? Or are you still having an issue?

Comment: The problem has been solved, it wouldn't assign anything to the view state varaible even though i was doing a query on button click. It worked for a while, though when i went to insert more values i got the same error as before. I wrapped this around an update panel and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CommandArgument property of `Button2` to attach the QuizID to it.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnCommand="Button2_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Then the method would look like this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
```

In `Button1_Click`you can assign the quizId like this:

```
Button2.CommandArgument = quizid;
```

A reason for the problem in general could be that the ViewState is affected by the code that switches between Views. Each time the View changes there's also a postback. This might explain why the ViewState does not hold the value anymore.